# How can I install the RT5370 WiFi dongle driver on Arch Linux?

Tags: archlinux, wireless

I would like to get the [Ralink RT5370](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/02_products/product.php?sn=1018) module to work on the Pi, but I couldn't find any tutorial related to the Arch Linux. How can I install the RT5370 WiFi dongle driver on Arch Linux?

I found [these instructions](http://raspberry-pi-notes.blogspot.de/2012/05/rt5370-cheap-micro-usb-wireless-dongle.html), but they are for a Debian system and I don't know how to do the equivalent thing in Arch Linux.

Comment: What have you found so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply installing 'wireless-tools' was enough for udev to pick it up and load the correct module at next boot. Using 'lsmod' I believe the module is 'rt2x00usb'.

After that and following the instructions for wpa_supplicant and I was connected to my wireless: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_Supplicant

Comment: *Timesaver:* I think you mean "wireless_tools" ;) `pacman -Sy wireless_tools`.