# Does this WiFi adapter work with my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: wireless, peripherals

The one I'm looking at is [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Mini-150Mbps-USB-WiFi-Wireless-Adapter-150M-LAN-Card-802-11n-g-b-with-Antenna-UK-/350719596686?). It was mentioned once [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=23401), but I just want to be sure before purchasing, because it's not listed on the list of verified peripherals.

Comment: WRT the RT5370 : http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1394/how-can-i-install-the-rt5370-wifi-dongle-driver-on-arch-linux But do scan the elinux verified peripherals page as that chipset is mentioned there a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to chipset. This one shows **Ralink RT5370**. As per [Wiki](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals) page on eLinux this chipset generally works with RPi. Search through **[Verified peripherals](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters)** page for more info. Some users reported that they installed drivers manually.